# Limit CPU usage for flash in Firefox?

Tags: windows, linux, firefox, flash, cpu-usage

How can we limit the CPU usage of Flash plugins in Firefox ?

I do not want to disable Flash, but I don't need to Flash objects to run at full speed either, in order to save battery power.

Comment: That Flash has *always* been such a CPU-hog has always annoyed me. It seems like everybody (users, Macromedia, Adobe, critics) were blinded to its seriously limiting annoyance by its usefulness. ¬_¬ As a result, little if anything has ever been done to optimize it to run better. ಠ╭╮ಠ

Answer (score 4):

I install NoScript on every system with Firefox, which blocks Flash along with Java and Javascript until I allow it from particular sites. This cuts down on sites loading flash widgets for something ridiculous like their site banner, or advertisements that are sneaky and hiding.

It also has the added benefit of security. Yes, its a pain to whitelist sites you trust, and you *really* must be careful of what you're going to allow; whitelisting everything defeats the purpose of the plugin. Security and convenience are mutually exclusive, anyway.

Comment: "I do not want to disable flash"... was a little broader than that : I *do* want to launch the flash applet, but not at full speed. Otherwise, I just use flashblock :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run the flash in the background it can be done by creating a new blank tab. Since now the "Flash Tab" is in the background it'll not consume so much processing power. I think the main cause of flash processing usage is for animation which is up to the developer to fix it.

Comment: +1 for the background tab (for flash-enabled music streaming). But usually i cannot just put it on the background

Comment: For me it does not work. It can be on another workspace, on a hidden window and on a hidden tab, but it still uses 99% of my CPU. The worst peace of software around... :-(